# Fill a quadrant with PGFplots and axis equal=true

Tags: pgfplots

I need to fill quadrant three and want to use `axis equal=true`. However, using this setting changes the minimum value of x. How do I adjust this to fill the entire quadrant independent of `axis equal=true` or `axis equal=false`.

The MWE below produces the result I want, but not if I uncomment the `axis equal=true` line.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\newcommand*{\XAxisMin}{-4.5}
\newcommand*{\XAxisMax}{4.5}
\newcommand*{\YAxisMin}{-4.5}
\newcommand*{\YAxisMax}{4.5}

\begin{axis}[%axis equal=true,
    axis y line=center, axis x line=middle, axis on top=true,
    xmin=\XAxisMin, xmax=\XAxisMax, ymin=\YAxisMin, ymax=\YAxisMax, 
] 

\fill[red!40]
    (axis cs:\XAxisMin,\YAxisMin) -- 
    (axis cs:0.0,\YAxisMin) -- 
    (axis cs:0.0,0.0) -- 
    (axis cs:\XAxisMin,0.0) -- 
    cycle;

% Based on Jake's solution, this should have worked, but produces identical results for me (PGFversion: 2.10)
%        \fill[green!40]
%       (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- 
%       (axis cs:0.0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- 
%       (axis cs:0.0,0.0) -- 
%       (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0.0) -- 
%       cycle;


\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Threeapproaches:

- Use the `rel axis cs` coordinate system, which places (0,0) in the lower left corner of the plot and (1,1) in the upper right
- Use the anchors `current axis.left of origin` and `current axis.below origin`, which are the projections of the axis origin on the left and lower plot edge, respectively
- or, if you're using the CVS version of PGFplots read the current value of `xmin` and `xmax` using `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}`

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\newcommand*{\XAxisMin}{-4.5}
\newcommand*{\XAxisMax}{4.5}
\newcommand*{\YAxisMin}{-4.5}
\newcommand*{\YAxisMax}{4.5}

\begin{axis}[axis equal=true,
    axis y line=center, axis x line=middle, axis on top=true,
    xmin=\XAxisMin, xmax=\XAxisMax, ymin=\YAxisMin, ymax=\YAxisMax, 
] 

\fill[orange!50] (axis cs:0,0) rectangle (rel axis cs:1,1);

\fill[green!70!black] (current axis.right of origin) rectangle (current axis.below origin);

\fill[blue!50]
    (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax})
    rectangle (axis cs:0,0) node [pos=0.5,text=white] {CVS only};

\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image: pgfplots with coloured quadrants]

Comment: Updated MWE to use `pgfkeysvalueof` but this produces identical results.

Comment: Oh sorry, it seems the `\pgfkeysvalueof` approach only works in the CVS version of PGFplots. The first approach should work with the current version though.

Comment: Do the first two approaches (`rel axis cs` and `current axis.right of origin`) not work in your case?

Comment: Yep, all three work now that I updated to the latest 2010 TeXLive.